# How to add a model class to room database in kotlin

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I have a save model that I need to add to my database. How can I import them into my database. Below is the model class.

```
{
"AccountNumber": "S234567",
"ActionRequiredID": "6,7",
"AdditionalRemarks": "",
"AndroidVersion": "31",
"AntennaTypeID": 6,
"AppVersion": "2.1.3",
"CTRatio": "",
"CategoryID": 1,
"CurrentMeterSealNumber": "thhjj",
"CycleName": "Nov-2022",
"EndTime": "2022-11-07 12:05:51",
"ICCIDNumber": "thb",
"Images": [
    {
        "ID": 0,
        "PicFormat": "jpg",
        "PicName": "S23456-TRS_6-TI1-team1_2022-11-07_17-35-05.jpg",
        "PicPath": "/storage/emulated/0/Download/team1/MReader/troubleshoot/Troubleshooting-Nov-2022/Photos/",
        "PicSize": "36 KB",
        "PictureTypeID": 18,
        "ServiceID": 5,
        "SurveyID": 6
    }
],
"IsGPSEnabled": true,
"IsLiveGPS": true,
"IsOnline": true,
"Latitude": 11.0501224,
"LocationAccuracy": 9.133,
"LocationProvider": "fused",
"Longitude": 76.9678775,
"MeterLocationID": 1,
"MeterModelID": 5,
"MeterSerialNumber": "61604448",
"NewMeterSealNumber": "",
"PingTestID": 1,
"ReasonForFailureID": "5",
"ReasonID": 39,
"Remarks": "",
"Seal1": "",
"Seal2": "",
"Seal3": "",
"Seal4": "",
"ServiceID": 5,
"SignalLevelID": 2,
"SimInField": "cghb",
"StartTime": "2022-11-07 12:05:05",
"StatusID": 12,
"StatusTroubleshootID": 4,
"UserID": 161,
"WorkOrderID": 6,
"WorkOrderNumber": "TRS_6",
"reason": "Completed",
"status": "Completed"
```

}

The information other than List<Images> needs to be added in a separate table called "ReplacedData" and images in "Images".

What should I do and what is the query for this?

Comment: The image object in `Images` array can represent a another table with one to many relationship ..  have u tried it ? add `Image` data class with question and the outer one also .

Comment: @ADM, can you be clear with your response? I can't get you.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 Create an @Entity (aka a table) annotated class based on the model, the table name being ReplacedData (according to *The information other than List needs to be added in a separate table called "ReplacedData"*) class with the List field having the @Ignore annotation.

Step 2 Create an @Entity (the 2nd table )annotated class based on the Image class with an additional field to store the Primary Key of the owning ReplacedData row (assuming a 1-many relationship i.e. the image can have one parent Replaced Data)

- optionally include a ForeignKey definition to enforce referential integiry

  - optionally have onDelete and onUpdate actions to CASCACDE and thus help maintain referential integrity

Step 3 Create a POJO for extracting ReplacedData rows along with the images (the children) where the class in Step1 is @Embedded and the class in Step2 is an @Relation

For example consider this working example (with cut down classes):-

**Step 1**

```
@Entity
data class ReplacedData(
    @PrimaryKey
    val replacedDataId: Long?=null,
    val AccountNumber: String,
    val ActionRequired: String,
    val AdditionalRemarks: String,
    val AndroidVersion: Int,
    val AppVersion: String,
    /* etc */
)
```

- Note not sure if AccountNumber would be unique and suitable for primary key so added replacedDataId.

**Step 2**

```
@Entity(
    /* Optional but suggested to enforce referential integrity */
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity =  ReplacedData::class,
            parentColumns = ["replacedDataId"],
            childColumns = ["parentReplacedData"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class Images(
    @PrimaryKey
    val imageId: Long?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val parentReplacedData: Long,
    val ID: Long,
    val PicFormat: String,
    /* etc */
)
```

- again specific primary key added
- Foreign Keys with CASCADE so referential integrity will be enforced and maintained

**Step 3**

```
data class ReplacedDataWithImages(
    @Embedded
    val replacedData: ReplacedData,
    @Relation(
        entity = Images::class,
        parentColumn = "replacedDataId",
        entityColumn = "parentReplacedData"
    )
    val imagesList: List<Images>
)
```

**Extras for the Demo**

```
data class TheModel(
    val replacedData: ReplacedData,
    val ImageList: List<Images>
)
```

- Something like the Model class (but cheated by simplifying it based upon the @Entity annotated classes)

:-

```
@Dao
interface AllDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(replacedData: ReplacedData): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(images: Images): Long

    @Transaction
    @Query("")
    fun insert(theModel: TheModel) {
        val replacedDataId = insert(theModel.replacedData)
        var imagesInserted=0
        if (replacedDataId > 0) {
            for(i: Images in theModel.ImageList) {
                if (insert(Images(parentReplacedData = replacedDataId, ID = i.ID, PicFormat = i.PicFormat)) > 0) {
                    imagesInserted +=1
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM replaceddata")
    fun  getAllFromReplacedDataWithImages(): List<ReplacedDataWithImages>
}
```

- 3 functions for inserting, note the 3rd that takes a **`TheModel`** and inserts the ReplacedData and the related Images (the children) that have the correct reference to the parent.

:-

```
@Database(entities = [ReplacedData::class,Images::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"thedatabase.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* to allow demo to use the main thread for brevity */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

- A basic @Database annotated class along with a singleton approach

  - note for brevity it allows the main thread to be utilised

**Lastly**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()

        val listOfImages = listOf<Images>(
            Images(parentReplacedData = 0, ID = 0, PicFormat = "JPG"),
            Images(parentReplacedData = -1, ID = 10, PicFormat = "GIF"),
            Images(parentReplacedData = 0, ID = 100, PicFormat = "GIF")
        )

        dao.insert(
                TheModel(
                    ReplacedData(
                        AccountNumber = "S1234567",
                        ActionRequired = "doit",
                        AdditionalRemarks = "quickly",
                        AndroidVersion = 31,
                        AppVersion = "2.3.1"
                    ),
                    listOfImages
                )
        )

        val sb = StringBuilder()
        for (rdwi in dao.getAllFromReplacedDataWithImages()) {
            sb.clear()
            for (i in rdwi.imagesList) {
                sb.append("\n\t ID=${i.ID}  Parent=${i.parentReplacedData} ImageId=${i.imageId} PivFormat=${i.PicFormat}")
            }
            Log.d("DBINFO"," Account Number=${rdwi.replacedData.AccountNumber} Image Count = ${rdwi.imagesList.size}. They are:-${sb}")
        }
    }
}
```

- some activity code to insert some data and then extract it writing pertintent data to the log.

When run (only designed to be run once) then the Log contains:-

```
D/DBINFO:  Account Number=S1234567 Image Count = 3. They are:-
         ID=0  Parent=1 ImageId=1 PivFormat=JPG
         ID=10  Parent=1 ImageId=2 PivFormat=GIF
         ID=100  Parent=1 ImageId=3 PivFormat=GIF
```

using App Inspection then:-

[image]

and

[image]